# Ruby on Rails - Association gets deleted before "before_destroy"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, associations, destroy

I have an object `A` that has_many `B`'s (simple association):

```
has_many :book_accounts, {
    dependent: :destroy
}
```

I was working on a `before_destroy` callback. I want to check and make sure that there are no `C`'s (which belongs_to `B`) and `D`'s (which belongs_to `C`) before destroying the `A`. I checked the log and all of the `B`'s are getting deleted before the callback causing the callback to crash.

Is this how Rails is supposed to work? Is there something I can do other than removing the `dependent: destroy` and manually destroying the `B`'s in an `after_destroy` callback? Or is that the go-to solution?

Comment: See the discussion here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3458

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is a very silly problem of rails & frustrating too. When you define a relationship in Rails, the `:dependent` option actually creates a callback. If you define a `before_destroy` callback after the relationship, then your callback isn't called until the relationships are destroyed.

The solution is to order your `before_destroy` callback before the declaration of the association.

Your code will be something like this

```
Class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy :check

  has_many :book_accounts, dependent: :destroy
End
```

Comment: I actually just found that out too (https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3458) , and was in the process of answering the question when you answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 24):

Have to add `prepend: true` to callback declaration:

```
before_destroy :do_something_before_children_removed, prepend: true
```

Comment: Link for docs: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#module-ActiveRecord::Callbacks-label-Ordering+callbacks

Comment: This is probably the best right answer